# Ubuntu 18.04 - jupyter notebook - Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, python3, jupyter

I am trying to run jupyter notebook on Ubuntu 18.04. After its installation by:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-notebook jupyter-core python-ipykernel
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev
pip3 install jupyter
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

it seemed to work perfectly by running `jupyter notebook`, but after rebooting, the systems returns this error:

`Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Jupyter seems to work by running this command:

`python3 -m IPython notebook`

but I would like to solve the problem with the command `jupyter notebook`.

Further information about my jupyter:

after `pip3 list | grep jupyter`:

```
jupyter (1.0.0)
jupyter-client (5.2.3)
jupyter-console (5.2.0)
jupyter-contrib-core (0.3.3)
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions (0.5.0)
jupyter-core (4.4.0)
jupyter-highlight-selected-word (0.2.0)
jupyter-latex-envs (1.4.4)
jupyter-nbextensions-configurator (0.4.0)
```

after `pip3 list | grep ipy`:

```
ipykernel (4.8.2)
ipython (6.5.0)
ipython-genutils (0.2.0)
```

after `jupyter --paths`:

```
config:
    /home/ale/.jupyter
    /usr/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /home/ale/.local/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /run/user/1000/jupyter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, my `PATH` variable has been somehow messed up, as it did not refer to the `./local/bin` directory correctly.

Comment: How did you corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue I was also facing because of the path,
Use `export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/` it will solve your problem